# ServiceStack ormlite with sql server: how to get a where clause with wildcards

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How do we get servicestack's ormlite to generate SQL that does a WHERE clause like this :

```
WHERE FirstName like '%joe%' OR lastname like '%joe%'
```

Currently if I do this :

```
db.Select<Person>.Where(x=> x.LastName.Contains(searchstring) || x.FirstName.Contains(searchstring));
```

it will generate a WHERE clause like the following without the needed wildcards:

```
WHERE FirstName like 'joe' OR lastname like 'joe'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String Contains expressions in OrmLite works as expected as seen in this [Live example on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=0bfd7759da39a484e69d2141dd642fc3) which uses the latest version of OrmLite:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();

public class Person
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

db.CreateTable<Person>();

db.Insert(new Person { FirstName = "Joeseph", LastName = "Smith" });

var rows = db.Select<Person>(x => 
    x.FirstName.Contains("joe") || x.LastName.Contains("joe"));
```

Which returns the valid match as expected and logs the query executed to the console:

```
DEBUG: SQL: CREATE TABLE "Person" 
(
  "Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  "FirstName" VARCHAR(8000) NULL, 
  "LastName" VARCHAR(8000) NULL 
); 

DEBUG: SQL: INSERT INTO "Person" ("FirstName","LastName") VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)
PARAMS: @FirstName=Joeseph, @LastName=Smith
DEBUG: SQL: SELECT "Id", "FirstName", "LastName" 
FROM "Person"
WHERE (upper("FirstName") like @0 OR upper("LastName") like @1)
PARAMS: @0=%JOE%, @1=%JOE%
```

OrmLite has been using parameterized queries for a while so you must be using an old version of OrmLite, if you upgrade to the latest **v4.5.0** of OrmLite it should work as expected.

Comment: yep -  I was way behind in my ormlite version for that project... updated it and it works fine